# Error when creating flextable in R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, flextable

I am trying to create a shiny app that will create flextables based on the 'Species' chosen . However I am running into an error (picture below) when running my code.

[image]

Current error
[image]

data

```
HSI.list = list(`Riverine Arctic Grayling` = structure(list(Species = c("ARGR", 
                                                                        "ARGR", "ARGR", "ARGR", "ARGR", "ARGR", "ARGR", "ARGR", "ARGR", 
                                                                        "ARGR", "ARGR", "ARGR"), `Model Variable` = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
                                                                                                                      "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "HSI"), value = c("0.857138", 
                                                                                                                                                                                          "1", "0.5", "not limiting", "0.1", "0.233333333333333", "not limiting", 
                                                                                                                                                                                          "1", "0.333333333333333", "1", "1", "0.1"), `Figure Caption` = c("Riverine Arctic Grayling", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Riverine Arctic Grayling", "Riverine Arctic Grayling", "Riverine Arctic Grayling", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Riverine Arctic Grayling", "Riverine Arctic Grayling", "Riverine Arctic Grayling", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Riverine Arctic Grayling", "Riverine Arctic Grayling", "Riverine Arctic Grayling", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Riverine Arctic Grayling", "Riverine Arctic Grayling"), River_Lake = c("River", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "River", "River", "River", "River", "River", "River", "River", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "River", "River", "River", "River"), old_new = c("old", "old", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "old")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "data.frame"), na.action = structure(17:201, names = c("17", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", "176", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201"), class = "omit")), 
                `Riverine Emerald Shiner` = structure(list(Species = c("EMSH", 
                                                                       "EMSH", "EMSH", "EMSH"), `Model Variable` = c("V3", "V5", 
                                                                                                                     "V7", "HSI"), value = c("0.6", "1", "1", "0.6"), `Figure Caption` = c("Riverine Emerald Shiner", 
                                                                                                                                                                                           "Riverine Emerald Shiner", "Riverine Emerald Shiner", "Riverine Emerald Shiner"
                                                                                                                     ), River_Lake = c("River", "River", "River", "River"), old_new = c("old", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "old", "old", "old")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(17:201, names = c("17", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "197", "198", "199", "200", "201"), class = "omit")))
```

Code for creating Shiny

note:
The code

```
x2 = input$sp
x = x2 %>% select(-Species, -`Figure Caption`, -River_Lake, -old_new)
```

is included because I dont want the - columns in the final flextable and x2 is used to specify the table caption using the `Figure Caption` column

```
library(flextable)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("HSI"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(inputId = "sp",
            label = "Choose Species:",
            choices = c("ARGR", "EMSH"))
       ),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("my_ft"))
  )
)
# Define server logic to summarize and view selected dataset ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  spInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$sp,
           "ARGR" = HSI.list$`Riverine Arctic Grayling`,
           "EMSH" = HSI.list$`Riverine Emerald Shiner`)
  
  })

    x2 = input$sp
    x = x2 %>% select(-Species, -`Figure Caption`, -River_Lake, -old_new)
  output$my_ft <- renderUI({
      flextable(x, cwidth = c(1,1) ) %>% bg(i = NULL, j = NULL, bg = "#333D47", part = "header") %>% 
      color(i = NULL, j = NULL, color = "white", part = "header") %>% 
      bold(i = NULL, j = NULL, bold = TRUE, part = "header") %>% 
      fontsize(i = NULL, j = NULL, size = 10, part = "all") %>% theme_box() %>% set_caption(caption = as_paragraph(as_chunk(paste0("XXX for ", unique(x2$`Figure Caption`)), props = fp_text_default(font.size = 10, font.family = "Arial", bold = TRUE)))) %>%
      font(i = NULL, j = NULL, fontname = fontname, part = "all")  %>%
      htmltools_value()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Current shiny
[image]

Example of table output I want to show in shiny if ARGR was specified.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to access the value of an `input` outside of a reactive context, i.e. `input$...` can only be used inside a `reactive` or `observe`r or a `renderXXX` function.

Hence, to fix you issue move the data wrangling inside the `renderUI`. Additionally I fixed some additional issue, i.e. there is no variable `x` in your code. Instead use the value of the `reactive` `spInput`.

```r
library(flextable)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("HSI"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "sp",
        label = "Choose Species:",
        choices = c("ARGR", "EMSH")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("my_ft"))
  )
)
# Define server logic to summarize and view selected dataset ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  spInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$sp,
      "ARGR" = HSI.list$`Riverine Arctic Grayling`,
      "EMSH" = HSI.list$`Riverine Emerald Shiner`
    )
  })

  output$my_ft <- renderUI({
    caption <- unique(spInput()$`Figure Caption`)
    fontname <- "Arial"

    x <- spInput() %>%
      select(-Species, -`Figure Caption`, -River_Lake, -old_new)

    flextable(x, cwidth = c(1, 1)) %>%
      bg(i = NULL, j = NULL, bg = "#333D47", part = "header") %>%
      color(i = NULL, j = NULL, color = "white", part = "header") %>%
      bold(i = NULL, j = NULL, bold = TRUE, part = "header") %>%
      fontsize(i = NULL, j = NULL, size = 10, part = "all") %>%
      theme_box() %>%
      set_caption(caption = as_paragraph(
        as_chunk(paste0("XXX for ", caption),
          props = fp_text_default(font.size = 10, font.family = "Arial", bold = TRUE)
        )
      )) %>%
      font(i = NULL, j = NULL, fontname = fontname, part = "all") %>%
      htmltools_value()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8267
```

[image]